The upper bound of a definite integral involving a derivative of an exponential function
I have a question.
Is there anyone who knows how to evaluate the upper bound of the absolute value of the following integral.
$$\int_{n}^{\infty} \Bigl(\frac{\exp(iax)}{x}\Bigr)^{(n)} \exp(ix) dx$$,
where $n$ is a positive integer, and $a$ is a real number and $0< a < 1$.
